# How to set required field validation while form post from API

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

> Form Type Class => TestFormType.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class TestFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'required' => true
                ]
            )
        ->add('gender',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'required' => true
                ]
            );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ApiBundle\Entity\Test',
            'csrf_protection'   => false,
            'validation_groups' => [ 'test' ]
        ));
    }    
}
```

> Entity => Test.php

```
/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", nullable=true, length=10, options={"comment" : "Name"})
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", nullable=true, length=10, options={"comment" : "Gender"})
 * @Assert\Choice(choices = {"true", "false"}, message = "Choose a valid option.", groups={"test"})
 */
private $gender;
```

I want to add condition for set field required. in annotation. Field value blank allow but field must available in request.

Have any possible way available?

Answer (score 1):

The "required" option is related to how the element is rendered in a HTML page and its not related to validation (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#required). It doesn't make sense in an API.

If you want to allow it to be false or empty string but not null you should use the NotNull constraint (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotNull.html) in your validation.